# How do I get the correlation as a vector from dcc garch and how do I draw more than one correlation – there is an error in using monthly data as well

Tags: r, time-series, portfolio, quantitative-finance, economics

I am using DCC Garch from the package rmgarch - the code you see above.
    The plot adjustment to my wishes does not fit and I am not sure because of the wrong titles of the x axis if the plot is taken the right time series I use since I have a really long time series. 
    I must use daily and monthly data as well and with monthly data I get problems, seeing in my results.

Therefor I used rcor(dcc.fit) to show the correlations generating by DCC Garch.

Now my first question is, if it is possible to get the correlation as one vector instead of what you are seeing as my result of rcor(dcc.fit), otherwise that would be a lot of work ?
  
My second question is that it does only work for replicate=2  assets otherwise I get an error message. I must look after some more correlations.
    Is it possible to get a matrix of time series of correlations? That means, to calculate all correlations as a time series at the same time and bind them to one matrix?

```
Correlation  A&B   A&C   B&C

T=1                 0,5       -0,5   0,15
T=2                 0,2       -0,3   0,23
T=3 ……

My code I used:

    >garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder   = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
    >dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec(replicate(2, garch11.spec) ), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
    >dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = returns)
    > rcorr = rcor(dcc.fit) 

#the outcome is above: the error is that this are monthly data and not 
#daily but it shows wrong dates. However, I want to have these correlations as a vector!! 

#1971-07-11 0.1197476
#1971-07-12 0.1199578

#further on.. but with right dates!

, , 1971-07-11 01:00:00

          Stock_1   Stock_2
Stock_1 1.0000000 0.1197476
Stock_2 0.1197476 1.0000000

, , 1971-07-12 01:00:00

          Stock_1   Stock_2
Stock_1 1.0000000 0.1199578
Stock_2 0.1199578 1.0000000

, , 1971-07-13 01:00:00

          Stock_1   Stock_2
Stock_1 1.0000000 0.1194465
Stock_2 0.1194465 1.0000000

, , 1971-07-14 01:00:00

           Stock_1    Stock_2
Stock_1 1.00000000 0.07949913
Stock_2 0.07949913 1.00000000

, , 1971-07-15 01:00:00

           Stock_1    Stock_2
Stock_1 1.00000000 0.08781321
Stock_2 0.08781321 1.00000000

Thank you in advance!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#to get time varying correlation
    rho.est.line <- list()
    rho.est.line = rcor(dcc.fit, type="R") # plot(rho.est.line[1,2,])
    outputcorr <- matrix((rho.est.line[1,2,]), nrow = dim(returns)[1], byrow = TRUE)
    rho.est = data.frame((outputcorr)) 
    rho.est.zoo = zoo(rho.est, order.by=index(returns[,1]))
```